# VKAPI как для андроид приложения получить оригинальное фото профиля?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Друзей авторизованного пользователя я получаю так

```
public List<VKApiUser> getFriends(){
    VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name, photo_200, photo_max_orig"));
    request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            listFriends = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
        }
    });
    return listFriends;
}
```

я думал параметр `photo_max_orig` даст оригинальную фотографию, но к сожалению это лишь увеличенная миниатюра. а как получить полную фотографию друга вообще не ясно.

Comment: Нужно воспользоваться методом `photos.get`, указав параметры `owner_id = ID человека`, `album_id = profile`, при условии, что параметр `rev = 1`, лучше всего через цикл проверять у каждого пользователя и сохранять в массив.

Comment: photos.get возвращает массив фотографий, как понять какой из них на аве у пользователя?

Comment: Указав параметры `count = 1` и `rev = 1`

Comment: Простите, но до меня никак не дойдет, что это за параметры `rev` и `count`?

Comment: Параметр `rev` - возвращает фотографии в обратном порядке (то, что нужно), а `count` - кол-во получаемых фотографий из альбома (в данном случае альбома профиля)

Comment: А понял, только не факт, что последний добавленный в альбом будет его настоящей аватаркой..Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Это факт, уже проверено десятками раз, не за что за подсказку)

Comment: В таком случае примного благодарен!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)))